# Invalid Symbol Characters

Tags: syntax, symbols

What unicode characters are invalid as a Symbol name?

Ideally I'm looking for a complete list.

Here is the current list

```
"\r\n~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|:;\"',<.>/?"
```

Comment: Perhaps, generate them all and try to use them?

Comment: Note that symbols cannot start with numbers as well.

Comment: something like `Catch@Symbol@FromCharacterCode/@Range[..]`  (no mathematica on this machine to work it out exactly )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`394` Unicode characters that are not valid Mathematica `Symbol`s can be found from

```
ss = Quiet@Table[{tem = "\\:" <> IntegerString[i, 16, 4], Symbol[tem]}, {i, 0, 16^4 - 1}];
notsym = Cases[ss, {z_, Symbol[__]} -> z]
```

The list is largely but not entirely complete.

To obtain the printable symbols for many of these unicodes, use

```
Map[FromCharacterCode[{FromDigits[StringDelete[#, "\\:"], 16]}] &, notsym]
```

for Mathematica 10.1 and later.  Otherwise, use (as suggested by Williams and Oleksandr R)

```
Map[FromCharacterCode[{FromDigits[StringReplace[ToString@#, "\\:" :> ""], 16]}] &, notsym]
```

{"", "  ", "
    ", "", "
    ", "
    ", " ", "!", "\"", "#", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "[", "\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "{", "|", "}", "~", "", " ", "¬", "°", "±", "·", "×", "÷", "π", " ", " ", " ", "‘", "’", "“", "”", " ", " ", "⁃", " ", "⁠", "⁢", "←", "↑", "→", "↓", "↔", "↕", "↖", "↗", "↘", "↙", "↤", "↥", "↦", "↧", "↼", "↽", "↾", "↿", "⇀", "⇁", "⇂", "⇃", "⇄", "⇅", "⇆", "⇋", "⇌", "⇐", "⇑", "⇒", "⇓", "⇔", "⇕", "⇤", "⇥", "⇵", "∀", "∂", "∃", "∄", "∆", "∇", "∈", "∉", "∋", "∌", "∍", "∏", "∐", "∑", "−", "∓", "∕", "∖", "∘", "√", "∝", "∞", "∣", "∥", "∦", "∧", "∨", "∫", "∮", "∯", "∲", "∳", "∴", "∵", "∶", "∷", "∼", "≀", "≁", "≂", "≃", "≄", "≅", "≇", "≈", "≉", "≍", "≎", "≏", "≐", "≠", "≡", "≢", "≤", "≥", "≦", "≧", "≨", "≩", "≪", "≫", "≭", "≮", "≯", "≰", "≱", "≲", "≳", "≴", "≵", "≶", "≷", "≸", "≹", "≺", "≻", "≼", "≽", "≾", "≿", "⊀", "⊁", "⊂", "⊃", "⊄", "⊅", "⊆", "⊇", "⊈", "⊉", "⊎", "⊏", "⊐", "⊑", "⊒", "⊓", "⊔", "⊕", "⊖", "⊗", "⊙", "⊢", "⊣", "⊤", "⊥", "⊨", "⊲", "⊳", "⊴", "⊵", "⊻", "⊼", "⊽", "⋀", "⋁", "⋂", "⋃", "⋄", "⋆", "⋚", "⋛", "⋠", "⋡", "⋢", "⋣", "⋨", "⋩", "⋪", "⋫", "⋬", "⋭", "⌈", "⌉", "⌊", "⌋", "⌢", "⌣", "〈", "〉", "␣", "⟂", "⟵", "⟶", "⟷", "⟸", "⟹", "⟺", "⤒", "⤓", "⥎", "⥏", "⥐", "⥑", "⥒", "⥓", "⥔", "⥕", "⥖", "⥗", "⥘", "⥙", "⥚", "⥛", "⥜", "⥝", "⥞", "⥟", "⥠", "⥡", "⥮", "⥯", "⥰", "⧏", "⧐", "⧦", "⩽", "⩾", "⪡", "⪢", "⪯", "⪰", "⫤", "　", "〚", "〛", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "\)", "\!", "\@", "\%", "\^", "\&", "\*", "\(", "\_", "\+", "\/", "\`", ""}

(Note: Nonfatal syntax errors above fixed courtesy of Silvia by replacing ":" by "\:".)

**Alternative Approach**

An alternative, faster approach to obtaining the non-`Symbol` characters above is

```
Quiet@Cases[Symbol[FromCharacterCode[#]] & /@ Range[0, 16^4 - 1], Symbol[z__] -> z]
```

{"", "", "\t", "\n", "", "\f", "\r", " ", "!", "\"", "#", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "[", "\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "{", "|", "}", "~", "", " ", "¬", "°", "±", "·", "*", "/", "π", " ", " ", " ", "'", "'", """, """, "
", "
", "⁃", " ", "", "⁢", "←", "↑", "→", "↓", "↔", "↕", "↖", "↗", "↘", "↙", "↤", "↥", "↦", "↧", "↼", "↽", "↾", "↿", "⇀", "⇁", "⇂", "⇃", "⇄", "⇅", "⇆", "⇋", "⇌", "⇐", "⇑", "⇒", "⇓", "⇔", "⇕", "⇤", "⇥", "⇵", "∀", "∂", "∃", "∄", "∆", "∇", "∈", "∉", "∋", "∌", "∍", "∏", "∐", "∑", "−", "∓", "∕", "∖", "∘", "√", "∝", "∞","∣", "∥", "∦", "∧", "∨", "∫", "∮", "∯", "∲", "∳", "∴", "∵", "∶", "∷", "∼", "≀", "≁", "≂", "≃", "≄", "≅", "≇", "≈", "≉", "≍", "≎", "≏", "≐", "!=", "≡", "≢", "<=", ">=", "≦", "≧", "≨", "≩", "≪", "≫", "≭", "≮", "≯", "≰", "≱", "≲", "≳", "≴", "≵", "≶", "≷", "≸", "≹", "≺", "≻", "≼", "≽", "≾", "≿", "⊀", "⊁", "⊂", "⊃", "⊄", "⊅", "⊆", "⊇", "⊈", "⊉", "⊎", "⊏", "⊐", "⊑", "⊒", "⊓", "⊔", "⊕", "⊖", "⊗", "⊙", "⊢", "⊣", "⊤", "⊥", "⊨", "⊲", "⊳", "⊴", "⊵", "⊻", "⊼", "⊽", "⋀", "⋁", "⋂", "⋃", "⋄", "⋆", "⋚", "⋛", "⋠", "⋡", "⋢", "⋣", "⋨", "⋩", "⋪", "⋫", "⋬", "⋭", "⌈", "⌉", "⌊", "⌋", "⌢", "⌣", "〈", "〉", "␣", "⟂", "⟵", "⟶", "⟷", "⟸", "⟹", "⟺", "⤒", "⤓", "⥎", "⥏", "⥐", "⥑", "⥒", "⥓", "⥔", "⥕", "⥖", "⥗", "⥘", "⥙", "⥚", "⥛", "⥜", "⥝", "⥞", "⥟", "⥠", "⥡", "⥮", "⥯", "⥰", "⧏", "⧐", "⧦", "⩽", "⩾", "⪡", "⪢", "⪯", "⪰", "⫤", "　", "[[", "]]", "<|", "|>", " ", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "<->", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "==", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ":>", "", "->", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "E", "I", "", "", "<<", ">>", "", "", "", "", "", "\)", "\!", "\@", "\%", "\^", "\&", "\*", "\(", "\_", "\+", "\/", "\`", "=="}

This list has one more character, `\:0000` and also displays a few of the characters differently.  Note also that one of the characters displays as a linefeed.  (I had to copy this second list in `InputForm`, which was unnecessary for the earlier list.)  The corresponding Unicode is given by

```
IntegerString[#, 16, 4] & /@ Quiet@Flatten@Cases[Symbol[FromCharacterCode[#]] & /@ 
    Range[0, 16^4 - 1], Symbol[z__] -> ToCharacterCode[z]]
```

{"0000", "0007", "0009", "000a", "000b", "000c", "000d", "0020", 
"0021", "0022", "0023", "0025", "0026", "0027", "0028", "0029", 
"002a", "002b", "002c", "002d", "002e", "002f", "0030", "0031", 
"0032", "0033", "0034", "0035", "0036", "0037", "0038", "0039", 
"003a", "003b", "003c", "003d", "003e", "003f", "0040", "005b", 
"005c", "005d", "005e", "005f", "0060", "007b", "007c", "007d", 
"007e", "007f", "00a0", "00ac", "00b0", "00b1", "00b7", "00d7", 
"00f7", "03c0", "2005", "2009", "200a", "2018", "2019", "201c", 
"201d", "2028", "2029", "2043", "205f", "2060", "2062", "2190", 
"2191", "2192", "2193", "2194", "2195", "2196", "2197", "2198", 
"2199", "21a4", "21a5", "21a6", "21a7", "21bc", "21bd", "21be", 
"21bf", "21c0", "21c1", "21c2", "21c3", "21c4", "21c5", "21c6", 
"21cb", "21cc", "21d0", "21d1", "21d2", "21d3", "21d4", "21d5", 
"21e4", "21e5", "21f5", "2200", "2202", "2203", "2204", "2206", 
"2207", "2208", "2209", "220b", "220c", "220d", "220f", "2210", 
"2211", "2212", "2213", "2215", "2216", "2218", "221a", "221d", 
"221e", "2223", "2225", "2226", "2227", "2228", "222b", "222e", 
"222f", "2232", "2233", "2234", "2235", "2236", "2237", "223c", 
"2240", "2241", "2242", "2243", "2244", "2245", "2247", "2248", 
"2249", "224d", "224e", "224f", "2250", "2260", "2261", "2262", 
"2264", "2265", "2266", "2267", "2268", "2269", "226a", "226b", 
"226d", "226e", "226f", "2270", "2271", "2272", "2273", "2274", 
"2275", "2276", "2277", "2278", "2279", "227a", "227b", "227c", 
"227d", "227e", "227f", "2280", "2281", "2282", "2283", "2284", 
"2285", "2286", "2287", "2288", "2289", "228e", "228f", "2290", 
"2291", "2292", "2293", "2294", "2295", "2296", "2297", "2299", 
"22a2", "22a3", "22a4", "22a5", "22a8", "22b2", "22b3", "22b4", 
"22b5", "22bb", "22bc", "22bd", "22c0", "22c1", "22c2", "22c3", 
"22c4", "22c6", "22da", "22db", "22e0", "22e1", "22e2", "22e3", 
"22e8", "22e9", "22ea", "22eb", "22ec", "22ed", "2308", "2309", 
"230a", "230b", "2322", "2323", "2329", "232a", "2423", "27c2", 
"27f5", "27f6", "27f7", "27f8", "27f9", "27fa", "2912", "2913", 
"294e", "294f", "2950", "2951", "2952", "2953", "2954", "2955", 
"2956", "2957", "2958", "2959", "295a", "295b", "295c", "295d", 
"295e", "295f", "2960", "2961", "296e", "296f", "2970", "29cf", 
"29d0", "29e6", "2a7d", "2a7e", "2aa1", "2aa2", "2aaf", "2ab0", 
"2ae4", "3000", "301a", "301b", "f113", "f114", "f360", "f361", 
"f380", "f382", "f383", "f384", "f39e", "f3a2", "f3a3", "f3a8", 
"f3a9", "f3ad", "f3b1", "f3b2", "f3b3", "f3b4", "f3bd", "f3be", 
"f3bf", "f3c6", "f3c7", "f3c8", "f3c9", "f3ce", "f3d0", "f3d1", 
"f3d2", "f3d3", "f3d4", "f3d5", "f3d6", "f3d7", "f3d8", "f3d9", 
"f3da", "f3db", "f3dc", "f3dd", "f3de", "f400", "f401", "f402", 
"f412", "f413", "f422", "f423", "f424", "f427", "f428", "f429", 
"f42b", "f42d", "f42e", "f42f", "f431", "f432", "f4a0", "f4a1", 
"f4a2", "f4a3", "f4a4", "f4a5", "f51e", "f51f", "f520", "f522", 
"f523", "f525", "f526", "f52a", "f52b", "f603", "f604", "f605", 
"f606", "f74b", "f74c", "f74d", "f74e", "f74f", "f760", "f761", 
"f762", "f765", "f767", "f76d", "f76e", "f76f", "f7c0", "f7c1", 
"f7c2", "f7c5", "f7c6", "f7c7", "f7c8", "f7c9", "f7ca", "f7cb", 
"f7cc", "f7cd", "f7d9"}

**Caution**

Being a `Symbol` and being useful as a `Symbol` are two different things.  For instance

```
Symbol[FromCharacterCode[62378]]
```

returns a nondisplaying symbol; i.e., the corresponding `Out` appears empty.  Nonetheless, a `Symbol` really is in that `Out` line.

```
Cases[{%}, z_Symbol -> True]
(* True *)
```

But, it is not obvious how one would use this or many others nondisplaying `Symbol`s.

Comment: There is a bug in your code some of the examples are identical except for a \ in front of the character.

Comment: There is no obvious way to remove the duplicates.  `StringLength` doesn't work.

Comment: @William they are not duplicates in reality; they are characters from the Unicode private use area that simply appear as if they are two individual characters.

Comment: @OleksandrR. You right answer updated to not use `StringDelete`.  It takes up two characters but only one its wierd.

Comment: @William *Mathematica* was designed (using Unicode) before Unicode was fully standardized. It is not completely free of (what we would now consider) bugs resulting from this non-standard Unicode handling. These particular characters are not allowed in symbol names because they are used in the construction of raw box expressions.

Comment: @OleksandrR. This is not ideal IMO.  I understand some of these characters but this is impractical.

Comment: @William  Your edit produces identical results to my earlier code.  Please role it back.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an edit history if you don't mind reverting it. I'll leave it as a comment then `Map[FromCharacterCode[{FromDigits[
 StringReplace[ToString@#, "\\:" :> ""], 16]}] &, notsym]` the first one doesn't work for me.  I think this one is the original but again it doesn't run for me in M10.  `Map[FromCharacterCode[{FromDigits[DeleteString[#, "\\:"], 
     16]}] &, notsym]`

Comment: @William  With `10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)`, both give the same results for me.  To do a rollback, click on "Edited 3 hours ago" just above your name.  A history of edits will appear, with yours the top one.  Click on "rollback" from among the list of options at the bottom of your edit to inactivate it.  As a bonus, you will receive a bronze badge, if you have not done a rollback before.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey `StringDelete` is new-in-10.1 function. For anyone using older versions, it seems @William's substitution is more useful. But, it's your answer, so you decide.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  Earlier today, I added an alternative approach that does not explicitly manipulate strings.  Nonetheless, it would do not harm to add still a third approach, and I shall.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I don't think the null operator should be included other then that it is accepted.

Comment: _"But, it is not obvious how one would use this or many others nondisplaying `Symbol`s."_ - Code obfuscation comes to mind.

Comment: @shrx  Interesting idea!