# "\:"; flagged as syntax error

Tags: syntax

While answering question [94032](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94032/invalid-symbol-characters/), I noticed that Mathematica 10.2 flagged

```
"\:" <> IntegerString[62378, 16, 4]
```

with a red bracket, apparently indicating a syntax error.  Nonetheless, it gave the correct result, `"\\:f3aa"`.  In contrast,

```
"\:"
IntegerString[62378, 16, 4];
%% <> %
```

gave the same answer (as expected) but without the red bracket.  However, replacing `"\:"` by `"\:";`caused the red bracket to return.  (Incidentally, `"\x"` and presumably similar strings, behaves the same way.)  What am I missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it depends on whether the string appears in a `RowBox` in the actual input boxes created in the FE.  The string by itself is not.  If it is inside any other function, it is put into a `RowBox`. I think the pure string form is not parsed, but the `RowBox` is.  For instance, `f["\:"]` generates a syntax error.  (BTW, this is only a guess.)

Comment: The code colorizing algorithm used by _Mathematica_ is far from perfect. There are many coloring anomalies.

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- shouldn't it be `"\\:"`? I thought `"\:"` alone is illegal? Maybe something like this: `ToExpression["\"" <> "\\:" <> IntegerString[945, 16, 4] <> "\""]`.

Comment: @Silvia  Despite the fact that what I did worked, I now see that it is incorrect syntax.  Interesting set of comments, though.  Thanks.

Comment: Writing `"\:"` is simply a syntax error.  Unfortunately Mathematica follows a very bad practise and tried to recover from the error ad interpret it as a two-character string anyway.  It does the same if I give it incorrect escape sequences like `"\s"`.  In the front end it doesn't even report the error.  In the terminal it does, but it still returns a two-character string instead of `Null` (as with most syntax errors).

Comment: Trying to "recover from errors" this way usually just ends up making more errors down the road and IMO it's bad design.  `"\\:f3aa"` is a 6-character string starting with a backslash, `"\:f3aa"` is a one character string and `"\:"` is a syntax error in the escape sequence.